# SQL Correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

I am trying to execute this query but am getting ORA-00904:"QM"."MDL_MDL_ID":invalid identifier. What is more confusing to me is the main query has two sub queries which only differ in the where clause. However, the first query is running fine but getting error for the second one. Below is the query.

```
select (
        select make_description
        from make_colours@dblink1
        where makc_id = (
                select makc_makc_id
                from model_colours@dblink1
                where to_char(mdc_id) = md.allocate_vehicle_colour_id
                )
        ) as colour,
    (
        select make_description
        from make_colours@dblink1
        where makc_id = (
                select makc_makc_id
                from model_colours@dblink1
                where mdl_mdl_id = qm.mdl_mdl_id
                )
        ) as vehicle_colour
from schema1.web_order wo,
    schema1.tot_order tot,
    suppliers@dblink1 sp,
    external_accounts@dblink1 ea,
    schema1.location_contact_detail lcd,
    quotation_models@dblink1 qm,
    schema1.manage_delivery md
where wo.reference_id = tot.reference_id
    and sp.ea_c_id = ea.c_id
    and sp.ea_account_type = ea.account_type
    and sp.ea_account_code = ea.account_code
    and lcd.delivery_det_id = tot.delivery_detail_id
    and sp.sup_id = tot.dealer_id
    and wo.qmd_id = qm.qmd_id
    and wo.reference_id = md.web_reference_id(+)
    and supplier_category = 'dealer'
    and wo.order_type = 'tot'
    and trunc(wo.confirmdeliverydate - 3) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: I can assure that it does have that column.

Comment: In case I write only **select qm.mdl_mdl_id as Vehicle_colour** it works fine.

Comment: `as vehicle_colour,` drop this comma

Comment: @Serg : Sorry, that was a typo while asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle usually doesn't recognise table aliases (or anything else) more than one level down in a nested subquery; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357):

> Oracle performs a correlated subquery when a nested subquery references a column from a table referred to a parent statement one level above the subquery. [...] A correlated subquery conceptually is evaluated once for each row processed by the parent statement.

Note the 'one level' part. So your `qm` alias isn't being recognised where it is, in the nested subquery, as it is two levels away from the definition of the `qm` alias. (The same thing would happen with the original table name if you hadn't aliased it - it isn't specifically to do with aliases).

When you modified your query to just have `select qm.mdl_mdl_id as Vehicle_colour` - or a valid version of that, maybe `(select qm.mdl_mdl_id from dual) as Vehicle_colour` - you removed the nesting, and the `qm` was now only one level down from it's definition in the main body of the query, so it was recognised.

Your reference to `md` in the first nested subquery probably won't be recognised either, but the parser tends to sort of work backwards, so it's seeing the `qm` problem first; although it's possible a query rewrite would make it valid:

> However, the optimizer may choose to rewrite the query as a join or use some other technique to formulate a query that is semantically equivalent.

You could also add hints to encourage that but it's better not to rely on that.

But you don't need nested subqueries, you can join inside each top level subquery:

```
select (
        select mc2.make_description
        from model_colours@dblink1 mc1,
            make_colours@dblink1 mc2  
        where mc2.makc_id = mc1.makc_makc_id
        and to_char(mc1.mdc_id) = md.allocate_vehicle_colour_id
    ) as colour,
    (
        select mc2.make_description
        from model_colours@dblink1 mc1,
            make_colours@dblink1 mc2
        where mc2.makc_id = mc1.makc_makc_id
        and mc1.mdl_mdl_id = qm.mdl_mdl_id
    ) as vehicle_colour
from schema1.web_order wo,
...
```

I've stuck with old-style join syntax to match the main query, but you should really consider rewriting the whole thing with modern ANSI join syntax. (I've also removed the rogue comma @Serg mentioned, but you may just have left out other columns in your real select list when posting the question.)

You could probably avoid subqueries altogether by joining to the make and model colour tables in the main query, either twice to handle the separate filter conditions, or once with a bit of logic in the column expressions. Once step at a time though...

Comment: Hi Alex, I did remove the other columns on purpose as they were not required. As per your comment **Oracle doen't recognise table aliases (or anything else) in more than one level of subquery** I tried to run the same query by removing the vehicle_colour selection and it works fine and that is the exact reason why I asked this question.

Comment: @SachinKumar - I'm not sure what you mean, that's what I tried to explain. I've expanded the answer a bit, maybe that is clearer now?

Comment: Ok, I think you got me wrong. What I wanted to tell was this. The current query is selecting two columns, if I run the query to select only one column (which is the first column) it works. If I do the same by commenting out the first column and run it to select only second column then it fails with the error that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SachinKumar - OK, but the second bit of documentation I quoted explains that!? Look at the execution plans for both single-column query and compare the filter and access predicates. Or trace the queries to see how they were rewritten byt the optimiser.

Comment: So by what you say, is it safe to say that a query which ran in one version of oracle may or may not run in another version ?

Comment: @SachinKumar - it may or may not run in another instance at the same version, or even in the same database on another day; it can depend on the data and whether/how the optimiser decides to rewrite the query, based on current statistics.

Comment: Wow. I knew that query will be rewritten or modified somehow depending on the statistics but never thought that it would actually affect the functionality itself.

Comment: @SachinKumar - it will get the same result (unless there are bugs in the optimiser, which does happen occasionally), so in that sense it doesn't affect the functionality of the query overall. But yes, the statistics etc. can affect whether a statement is parsed successfully or throws an error, in certain circumstances.

Comment: @SachinKumar - you can read about what the optmiser might do in the docs; here I think you specifically want to look at [subquery unnesting](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_transform.htm#TGSQL212).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Though I don't have proof of what is actually happening. I still take this as an answer to at least rewrite the query using joins rather than nested sub queries.